# Delete rows containing @ symbol in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I would like to know if there is any way of deleting any row containing the @ symbol in a text string.

I already tried :

```
DELETE FROM FilteredJobs WHERE Description LIKE '%[@]%'
```

but this returns 0 rows (I know there are 4)

I need to get this done within mySQL since there will be other mySQL functions to follow this task.

Comment: What are the square brackets for?

Comment: `DELETE FROM FilteredJobs WHERE Description LIKE '%@%'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM FilteredJobs WHERE Description LIKE '%@%'
```

It appears you were trying to use a regex character class containing the at symbol.  This won't work with `LIKE`, but it should work with `REGEXP`, e.g.

```
DELETE FROM FilteredJobs WHERE Description REGEXP '[@]'
```

Here is a demo showing that your approach would work using `REGEXP`:

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locate`, it returns the position of the sub string in the main value...

```
DELETE FROM FilteredJobs WHERE locate('@', Description) > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is something that I could think of, might not be the PERFECT answer but can definitely be tried:

```
UPDATE FilteredJobs SET Description = REPLACE(Description, '@', 'TO_BE_DELETED');
```

And then you can fire a normal DELETE query:

```
DELETE FROM FilteredJobs WHERE Description LIKE '%TO_BE_DELETED%';
```

Comment: A horrible solution when you just can use regexp instead.